# what is default resolution for windows mobile6.5 professional device

Tags: windows-mobile

can anyone tell me what is default resolution for windows mobile6.5 professional device ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default resolution; it varies by hardware configuration. Currently, the currently supported display modes on Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional devices are:

```
Resolution   DPI   Orientation              Small Icon   Large Icon
==========   ===   ===========              ==========   ==========
240×240      96    Square                   16×16        32×32
240×320      96    Portrait and Landscape   16×16        32×32
240×400      96    Portrait and Landscape   16×16        32×32
320×320      128   Square                   21×21        43×43
480×480      192   Square                   32×32        64×64
240×240      192   Portrait and Landscape   32×32        64×64
240×240      192   Portrait and Landscape   32×32        64×64
```

"In addition to these, Microsoft occasionally adds new configurations, original equipment manufacturers (OEMs), and mobile operators. Also, some devices support dynamic screen orientation rotation. For example, a device with a 240×320 portrait display may rotate to a 320×240 landscape display when its keyboard slides out." [MSDN writer Michael Saffitz concludes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546609.aspx#id0070003) that "more than ever, it's critical that your application not assume one or more screen characteristics and instead be written to dynamically adapt and support all resolutions, orientations, and at least 96 DPI and 131 DPI." To that end, Microsoft has put together some resources for developers who write software that will deployed across different display configurations. They call it "Adaptable Applications", and as a developer it means that you spend some extra effort thinking about how your app is going to look in different platforms. If you're interested in that, Saffitz's article is a good place to start, as well as this [MSDN WebCast: 24 Hours of Windows Mobile Application Development: Dealing with Different Form Factors](http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/detail/webcastdetails.aspx?seriesid=86&webcastid=5056)

Comment: The last 2 lines should probable be: 480x640 and 480x800 ?